# running cmd programs needs path

Tags: windows, cmd, pascal, lazarus

I am using Laarus to write a simple program I have the answer kind of my code below. How do I make an external program start in a specific directory?

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
F: File;
 i, filehandle: Integer;
runprogram:TProcess;
begin
  runprogram :=Tprocess.create(nil);
  runProgram.CommandLine:='C:\Users\stran\Downloads\123\dcars.exe';
  runProgram.Execute;
  Runprogram.free; 
  //This works but I need to navigate their first for the program
  //to pick up its cmd line preferances.ini file
  //I need to or have the program startin C:\...\...\..
  //in cmd(prompt)cd C:\Users\stran\Downloads\123\
  //then dcars.exe and it picks up its ini file and runs
end;
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: how to pass the path to the execute file as explained in code commments

Comment: I guess you need to set .CurrentDirectory.

Comment: But How I know I need to do it but HOW

Comment: runprogram.CurrentDirectory := '....

Comment: thanks so obvious once you see it none of the examples had it

Comment: You're welcome. Try the documentation when you can't find an example. It might come to be useful: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/fcl/process/tprocess.currentdirectory.html

Answer (score 2):

Set the [currentdirectory](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/process/tprocess.currentdirectory.html) property before you do *.Execute*. E.g.

```
 runprogram.currentdirectory:='C:\Users\stran\Downloads\123\';
```